# Elements of order $d$ are all powers of each other in $U_p$ without assuming $U_p$ cyclic

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Without knowing that $U_p$ is already cyclic, is there a good way to show that all elements of a given order $d \mid p-1$ are powers of each other? That is, if we are able to find an element of order $d$, then all elements of order $d$ are its powers. I am trying to show that there is only $\varphi(d)$ of these elements, since once we find one element of order $d$, say $a$, then all the others can be found via $a^k$, for $k$ coprime to $d$.

So far I've tried doing a proof by contradiction. If we have a second element of order $d$ that is not $a$, say $b$, then $a^xb^y$ must have order $d$ as well for all $x, y$. However, there doesn't seem to be enough elements to exceed the limit of $p-1$.

The only way I have managed to prove this is first doing it for divisors that are prime powers through using polynomials on $U_p$, and then using multiplicativeness of $\varphi$. I am wondering whether there is some other solution that is more straightforward.

Comment: Are you familiar with cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: Only very slightly, and in the context of complex numbers. I would prefer not to involve polynomials, since I have one way of solving the problem by considering the roots of $x^{p_i^{k_i}} - 1$ on $U_p$. This question feels like it should have a simple solution, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $a,b$ are elements of order $d$.

Then $a,a^{2},...,a^{d-1}, a^d=1$ are $d$ distinct roots of the polynomial $X^d-1$, and therefore are **all roots of this polynomial.**

Next, $b^d=1$ and hence, $b$ is a root of $X^d-1$. Therefore, by the above there exists some $1 \leq k \leq d$ such that $b=a^k$.

This proves that $b=a^k$.

**Note**

$$d=\mbox{ord}(b)=\mbox{ord}(a^k)=\frac{d}{\mbox{gcd(d,k)}} \Rightarrow \mbox{gcd(d,k)}=1$$

You can use this to prove the stronger statement:

Assume that there exists an element $a$ of order $d$, then $b$ is an element of order $d$ if and only if there exists some $1 \leq k \leq d$ with $\mbox{gcd(d,k)}=1$ such that
$$
b=a^k \,.
$$
This immediately gives that there are either $0$ or $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$.

If you are familiar with the Fundamental Theorem of ALgebra, it implies that there exists at least one element of order $d$, so combined with the above you can deduce that there are exactly $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$.